# How to properly install docker on vagrant managed machine behind proxy

Tags: docker, proxy, vagrant

I have Windows 7 environment. I'd like to play with docker and manually working with virtualbox is not working for me. I'm trying to setup vagrant to create machine for me, but fails hard because corporate proxy.

I have already installed vagrant proxy plugin, but so far I have no success with that line `config.vm.provision :docker` as this error says `Cannot initiate the connection to 3128:80` the proxy is not properly set. 
It just tries to run **apt-get**, but maybe as sudo which can be the issue as env properties will not be kept.

Anyone succesfully provisioned docker behind corporate proxy?

UPDATE
My vagrant file

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  # setting up proxy
  config.proxy.http     = "real_proxy_url:3128"
  config.proxy.https    = "real_proxy_url:3128"
  config.proxy.no_proxy = "/var/run/docker.sock,localhost,127.0.0.1"
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.10.101"
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.memory = 2048
    vb.cpus = 2
  end
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
    wget -qO- https://get.docker.com/ | sh
  SHELL
end
```

UPDATE 2
This is my final vagrant file, I was unable to resolve the problem with missing systemctl command in ubuntu, so I have switched to debian and all is good to go

```
  # -*- mode: ruby -*-
  # vi: set ft=ruby :
  Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "debian/jessie64"
  # setting up proxy
  config.proxy.http     = "http://real_proxy_url:3128""
  config.proxy.https    = "http://real_proxy_url:3128""
  config.apt_proxy.http = "http://real_proxy_url:3128""
  config.proxy.no_proxy = "localhost,127.0.0.1"
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.10.101"
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.memory = 2048
    vb.cpus = 2
  end
  config.vm.provision :docker
  config.vm.provision :docker_compose
 end
```

Comment: config.proxy.no_proxy = "/var/run/docker.sock,localhost,127.0.0.1" in `Vagrant` file. see https://github.com/tmatilai/vagrant-proxyconf/issues/97

Comment: I have it set. This resolves some problem for docker not for apt-get before the docker is even installed will add my Vagrant file.

Comment: On provisioning start is says `default: Configuring proxy for Apt...`. I tried to set export proxy before the wget, but still no succes.

Comment: I suggest you also to set `config.apt_proxy.http = "real_proxy_url:3128"`

Comment: Some progress, but now I fail with `W: Failed to fetch https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/trusty/stable/binary-amd64/Packages`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197977/discussion-between-zveratko-and-linpy).

Answer (score 0):

First add `config.apt_proxy.http = "real_proxy_url:3128"` to your `vagrant` file.

then follow the documentaion to install `docker`:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove docker docker-engine docker.io containerd runc
$ sudo apt-get install -y
$ sudo apt-get -y install \
  apt-transport-https \
  ca-certificates \
  curl \
  gnupg-agent \
  software-properties-common
  $ curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
  $ sudo apt-key fingerprint 0EBFCD88


$ sudo add-apt-repository \
   "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
   $(lsb_release -cs) \
   stable"
$ sudo apt-get -y update
$ sudo apt-get -y install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
```